# Making a button change when an input is selected

Tags: jquery, button, input

I am trying to make a Yes/No input change the function of a button.  If the input is Yes then I want the button to be a hyper link, but if it is a no I want it to take you to the next div (once the button is clicked)

I have NO idea how to do this.

Here is what I have

I am imagining I need a jquery thing to start like this:

```
$('input:radio[name="yes"]').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        $('.1').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
        $('.2').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

I tried giving the buttons a different class and then trying to have the show up, but that wasn't working.

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="yes" value="Yes"/>Yes
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="No"/>No
</form>

<a href="#"><button>Yes</button></a>
<button class="no">No</button>
```

This is what the buttons would look like

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with this:

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eFC2j/)</kbd>

#### HTML:

```
 <input type="radio" name="button" value="Yes" />Yes
 <input type="radio" name="button" value="No" />No

 <button class='yes'>Yes</button>
 <button class="no">No</button>
```

#### jQuery:

```
 $('input:radio').change(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
      $('[class="yes"]').show().siblings('button').hide();
   } else {
      $('[class="no"]').show().siblings('button').hide();
   }
});
```

Try to group them with same name and try a change event on this radio button then show the corresponding button.

and even a better one:

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
  var rad = this.value.toLowerCase();
  $('[class="' + rad + '"]').show().siblings('button').hide();
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFC2j/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Awesome!  I was close on my idea lol  Ok so  when you load the page you  get the Yes and No Button to show then when you click Yes or No the other dissapears.  How do I make it so that only 1 button is visible the whole time, but button's function changes when the Yes or no is shown?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I can just set the CSS of the "no" to be display:none  I think that will work

Comment: Absolutely doing that will do as per your requirement.

Comment: I also came up with another idea, which was to set one of the inputs to selected!  I like this option better.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: out of curiosity why is the class=no in "[]"?

Comment: It is called attribute selector in jQuery like `[id="someId"] [name="someName"]` etc. depends on the attributes currently has an input.